# Unable to ssh with user created under Plesk (Amazon Ec2)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, plesk

I've manually installed Plesk under ubuntu instance (EC2),
and created a system user using Plesk, so When I try to SSH with that user I get: `Permission denied (publickey).`
I have a pem key that I use to ssh with ubuntu user.

My main goal is to have a git clone from bitbucket, And I understood that the right user should do the cloning so it'll succeed. I've tried with many methods and looked everywhere!

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so I found the solution.

First I had to login as the main user (for me it was ubuntu) using the pem key provided with Amazon.

Then I had modify this file: `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
and changed `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes`

Then I had to restart the ssh service: `sudo service ssh restart`

And that was the end of it!

PS
when I was logged in with Plesk user, I had to activate ssh-agent like so: `ssh-agent /bin/bash`

I hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo service ssh restart ->not work
```

This will not work, use this one instead.

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

Comment: ssh is not a service, it is a command to connect to sshd service, sshd is a service